# Can I use an xlsx file (text) with quanteda? I can import the file using read_excel, but when I try to tokenise it I get a non-character object error

Tags: tokenize, quanteda

I have an excel sheet with online comments, I load it into R with read_excel, it shows in the environment with the correct number of variables and observations, but when I try to tokenise it quanteda says: "Error: tokens() only works on character, corpus, list, tokens objects." If I use corpus() on the data.frame I get a 1 document, 1 Tokens, 1 Sentences.

I was hoping that quanteda could tokenise the imported data.frame. I tried creating a new object with characterize(), but that didn't work either; I also tried saving it as .rda, to no avail.

Comment: You would need to provide a reproducible example, but I suggest you look at `?quanteda::corpus.data.frame` since that describes how to convert your document into a **quanteda** corpus, which you can then tokenise. You will need to specify `text_field`.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof. Benoit, will take a closer look at the help page for corpus(); hopefully I'll figure it out.